# sitemap.xml turkish character

Tags: php, xml

that's my php code;

```
//Encode ANSI
function donustur($str){
    $eski = array('Ç', 'Ş', 'Ğ', 'Ü', 'İ', 'Ö', 'ç', 'ş', 'ğ', 'ü', 'ö', 'ı', ' ','&');
    $yeni = array('c', 's', 'g', 'u', 'i', 'o', 'c', 's', 'g', 'u', 'o', 'i', '-','&amp;');
    return str_replace($eski,$yeni,$str);
}

header('Content-type: text/xml');
echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"ISO8859-9\" ?>\n";
echo "<urlset xmlns=\"http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap/0.84\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xsi:schemaLocation=\"http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap/0.84 http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap/0.84/sitemap.xsd\">";

echo "<url>
  <loc>http://www.sitem.com/</loc>
  <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
</url>";

$d = "\t<changefreq>daily</changefreq>\n";

$kategoriCek = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM kategoriler");
while($kat = mysql_fetch_array($kategoriCek)){
   echo "<url>\n";
   echo "\t<loc>http://www.sitem.com/".$kat['id']."-".donustur(strtolower($kat['kategoriadi']))."-kategori.html</loc>\n";
   echo $d;
   echo "</url>\n";
}

echo "</urlset>\n";
```

output;

```
<loc>http://www.sitem.com/93-??-guvenl?k-kategori.html</loc>
```

I want should be like that;

```
<loc>http://www.sitem.com/93-is-guvenlik-kategori.html</loc>
```

UTF-8 and UTF-8 not BOM or **encoding="ISO8859-9"**, **encoding="UTF-8"** doesn't work it.

How we do solve?

Thank you for your interest.
Good works..

Comment: `strtolower` is not multi-byte save, that’s likely to be the problem here. And why don’t you create your XML as UTF-8 in the first place? And if you put characters outside the ASCII range into your URLs, you should URL-encode them properly.

Comment: I am use `mb_strtolower` don't work.. Now, I am translate to UTF-8 encode, but not changed..

Comment: In which encoding is that *PHP file* you ask about here?

Answer (score 0):

Sitemaps following the [Sitemap protocol](http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html) format must be UTF-8 encoded:

> The Sitemap protocol format consists of XML tags. All data values in a Sitemap must be [entity-escaped](http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html#escaping). The file itself must be UTF-8 encoded.

So for example what you do at the very beginning:

```
 <?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"ISO8859-9\" ?>
```

Is already wrong because that encoding is not supported by XML sitemaps. As you also wrote in your question that you just interchanged the string there (e.g. to "UTF-8") but you lost no word at all about the encoding of the actual output, you most likely just output bad encoded character data and perhaps even XML.

There are two things you can do to greatly improve this and reduce the chance of such errors:

1. Find out in which encoding the characters you have for input are. Convert those into UTF-8 before passing them into the output processing.
2. Use a library like [SimpleXML](http://php.net/book.simplexml) or [XMLWriter](http://php.net/book.XMLWriter) to generate the XML. You do not need to do that all your own. These libraries already take care of the encoding.